# DependencyProperty not Written in Derived Class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inheritance, dependency-properties

I'm working with WPF/XAML and defined my own view based on `window` called `container`. `container` has a DependencyProperty called `CurrentElementProperty` linked to the property `CurrentElement`. My problem is that the `set` method of the property is never called from `DerivedContainer`. If I change the `typeof(Container)` to `typeof(DerivedContainer)` during property registering it gets called. I'm almost certain, I'm doing something wrong during registering.

Definition of `Container`

```
class Container : Window
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentElementProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "CurrentElement",
            typeof(Element),
            typeof(Container),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                null,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
    public Element CurrentElement
    {
        get
        {
            return (Element)this.GetValue(Container.CurrentElementProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(Container.CurrentElementProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML of `DerivedContainer` (I removed the standard XML namespace definitions)

```
<local:Container x:Class="ns.DerivedContainer"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ns">
  <local:Container.CurrentElement>
    <Element />
  </local:Container.CurrentElement>
</local:Container>
```

Code behind `DerivedContainer`

```
public partial class DerivedContainer : Container
{
    public DerivedContainer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My problem is that the set method of the property is never called from DerivedContainer

This is not a problem - it is expected behavior. WPF calls `SetValue` directly rather than going through the wrapper. The wrapper is there for the convenience of other client code. If you need to do something when the property is set, you need to register a callback in your `DependencyProperty.Register` call.